# Extracting variables from Bottle or Jinja2 template

Tags: python, templates, variables, jinja2, bottle

I'm trying to grab the variables from Bottle templates so my Python application can see which variables are required when the template is finally rendered. Kind of like, select a template first, the template is read, the areas on the template are detected (e.g. `{{header}}`) and I can provide the variables assigned back to the rendering system.

I've had no luck in finding a way to do this as each time I have extracted the variable names as a string and there is no way to return a string as a variable name in the same format it is found in the template (e.g. `header` instead of `'header'`)

Any suggestions on this? I've tried using a dictionary to dynamically create key-value pairs but this doesn't work. Maybe I'm coming at it at the wrong angle... any other angles gladly accepted.

Comment: I eventually found the locals() function. Using locals() in a loop with the variable names as strings in a list I have managed to turn them into variable names. Is anyone aware of any security issues with this? I assume it's safer than using exec()?

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong... You're supposed to know which variables are required.

Comment: What I'm attempting at the moment is a way for a user, not a developer to select a template and then fill various regions of the template with information. It is so the template can be easily used in the system without knowing the programming underneath. The developer is not forced to know the names that the template designer has used in the template and this prevents an additional step of having to provide the variable names manually.